# Why don't we have ArrayAdapter's notifyDataSetChanged(row)

Tags: android

When I am doing Swing programming, `javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel` is having `fireTableCellUpdated(row, col)`, to let me specific which row and col of GUI I want to update.

However, when comes to `ArrayAdapter`, I realize they only provide `notifyDataSetChanged`. I was expecting I am having access to `notifyDataSetChanged(row)`, to let me update the item I am interested in. I do not want to update the entire list.

I was wondering why don't we have ArrayAdapter's notifyDataSetChanged(row). Or, am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was wondering why don't we have ArrayAdapter's notifyDataSetChanged(row).

Ask Google. ;-)

> Or, am I missing something?

Nope.

You are (by calling `notifyDataSetChanged()`) just telling the `ListView` to redraw the whole list, even if you just have to update a specific item. I believe Google have a good reason for why this was omitted, but as it stands, *you are perfectly* fine with calling `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Answer (score 1):

`notifyDataSetChanged()` does not take effect on specific child view, as you are asking. It sends signal for the listview/tablerows to be repopulated with new data. Therefore, entire View is told to redrawn with the new data using this method.

Watch this video to get more familiar adapters.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70